# How to printf the biggest number of some numbers I wrote In Scanf?

Tags: printf, scanf

```
public class test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int a;
        
        
        for(int i = 1; i > 0; ++i) {
            
            a = scanner.nextInt();
            
            if(a <= 0 & i != 1) {
                
                System.out.println("The largest number is ");
                
                break;
                
            }else if(a <= 0 & i == 1){
                
                System.out.println("No Number entered.");
                break;
                
            }else if(a <= 0){
                
                System.out.println("No Number entered.");
                break;
                
            }else
                
                System.out.println("Number "+i+": "+a);
        }
    }
}
```

### QUESTION

I want to scanf some numbers, for example, 3, 5 and 6.
after I scanf 0, it should printf the biggest number, in this example, 6.

How do I write the code for that without using arrays (I am not allowed to use arrays)

I wrote the code that if I scanf 0 first, it tells me "No numbers entered".
and after I scanf several numbers, 0 is the number that breaks the loop and ends the program

Answer (score -1):

try this code :

int n;
scanf("%d",&n);

```
int a,result;
//result=-infiniti
result=-100000000;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a);
    if(a>result)
    {
        result=a;
    }
}
printf("%d",result);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).